# At what height will the tension of the string attached to a bob, given an initial velocity from the bottom, become zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, oscillators

Assuming a bob attached to a string is given a horizontal velocity u when it is at the bottom, what would be the height at which the tension of the bob would be zero (i.e the bob leaves the circular path). I know that the cos component of weight should be equal to the centripetal force, but I cannot formulate an equation for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean "string"?  If "spring" it will not be a circular path.

Comment: Yeah! I meant a string

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're looking for the radius needed to achieve velocity v:

$F=ma$

$F_G + F_T = m v^2 / r$

$mg = mv^2 / r$

$g= v^2/r$

$r = v^2/g$
[image: blue is bob, green is string, red are forces]

The radius needed is velocity (tangent to acceleration) squared divided by gravity acceleration

Comment: This assumes that the mass reaches the top of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

If the motion of the bob carries it to an angle θ above the position where the string is horizontal, then the tension plus a component of gravity must supply the centripetal acceleration: T + mg sin(θ) = m$v^2$/R.  Set T = 0 and use conservation of energy to find $v^2$ and then θ.